# Matrix of lists - Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix

I want to create a matrix of list, but when I create the lists inside the matrix it created a linked list, and I don't need that.

```
A=[[{}]*3]*3
result: [[{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}]]
A[0][2]['h1']=1
result: [[{'h1': 1}, {'h1': 1}, {'h1': 1}],
 [{'h1': 1}, {'h1': 1}, {'h1': 1}],
 [{'h1': 1}, {'h1': 1}, {'h1': 1}]]
```

Anyone knows how to avoid this? I need a list inside each field of the matrix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are initializing `A` with 3 references to the same list, and each of those lists is being initialized with 3 references to the same dictionary. Instead, try explicitly calling a constructor for each sublist and dictionary:

```
>>> A = [ [{} for _ in range(3) ] for _ in range(3) ]
>>> A[0][2]['h1']=1
>>> A
[[{}, {}, {'h1': 1}],
 [{}, {}, {}],
 [{}, {}, {}]
]
```

As a side note, ["linked list"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) generally refers to the data structure of the same name, rather than the case where you have multiple references to the same object.